# Quick sort : Why does classic Hoare partition scheme does not return right pivot?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I implemented the Hoare's partition scheme for quick sort as it is in the book *Introduction to Algorithms* :

```
public static void sortHoare(int[] arr) {
    quickSortHoare(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

public static void quickSortHoare(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int indexPartition = partitionHoare(arr, left, right);
        quickSortHoare(arr, left, indexPartition);
        quickSortHoare(arr, indexPartition + 1, right);
    }
}

// should return a pivot integer, which divides the original array into one left and one right array
private static int partitionHoare(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    int pivot = arr[left];
    int i = left - 1;
    int j = right + 1;

    while (true) {
        while (arr[--j] > pivot);
        while (arr[++i] < pivot);
        if (i >= j) {
            return j;
        }
        swap(arr, i, j);
    }
}
```

So it sorts my array correctly, but what I don't understand is that, it does actually not return the pivot that divides.

For example my array is : `[5, -1, 3, 10, 2, -9]`

The pivot is 5. The array becomes :`[-9, -1, 3, 2, 10, 5]` when it returns j. and it actually returns j = 3 (value => 2), but it's neither the pivot nor the element divides that two partitions (because 3 is greater than 2)...

[image]

Comment: All the partition does is separate the elements into two groups: those that are smaller than the pivot, and those that are larger than the pivot. The pivot itself, and any elements equal to the pivot, can be in either group. So in your example, -9, -1, 3, and 2 are all smaller than the pivot, and 10 and 5 are greater than or equal to the pivot. The order of elements within a group doesn't matter. Index 3 points to the last element of of the left group.